# How to save a SQLite Data Base

Tags: c#, winforms, sqlite

I am currently working on an internship project called "Task manager", which keeps basic info about company employees, and shows assigned tasks.

I have an Employee Class that looks like this:

```
public class Employee
{
    public  string _name { set; get; }
    public  string _surname { set; get; }
    public  string _position { set; get; }
    public  string _adress { set; get; }
    public  string _phone { set; get; }
    public  string _email { set; get; }
    public  int _ID { set; get; }
    public List<Task> Assigned_Task = new List<Task>();

    public Employee(string name, string surname, string position, string adress, string phone, string email)
    {
        _name = name;
        _surname = surname;
        _position = position;
        _adress = adress;
        _phone = phone;
        _email = email;
        _ID = Controller.Counter;
        Controller.Counter++;
    }
}
```

A task class:

```
 public class Task
 {
     public string _description { set; get; }
     public string _task_name { set; get; }
     public string _deadline { set; get; }

     public Task(string name, string descript, string deadline)
     {
         _task_name = name;
         _description = descript;
         _deadline = deadline; 
     }
 }
```

There is also an almighty god object Controller class, containing a few Lists that keep all the employees and the tasks. (I would prefer not to show this class due to the poor quality of the code).

In my main form I have got two lists that contain the names of the workers and the tasks, a few options to add new employees and tasks, and a save button.

I am currently using SQLite for saving, but this is my first time using it.

My questions are:

1. How can I save the Employee List with tasks so that I can easily load it later
2. How do I save the Employees to the database in general

Answer (score 0):

1. Install SQLite from nuget
2. Use Entity Framework Code First to
   map your employee/task models to SQLite, here is how: [Code
   First](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/en-en/data/jj193542.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can easily use SQLite in .Net using ADO.net with this provider:
http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/index.wiki

If you don't want to use any ORM (is may be a bit complicated for the first time) then just save your `Tasks` and `Employees` lists to two different tables. You will also need to add Employee ID column to each task table to connect them back later.

Then you can just select values joining two to tables as needed.